# Refresh Datatable after row deletion

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using PF 3.0RC1 with JSF 2.0.

I have a datatable and on each row I have a delete button. As soon as I press the delete the corresponding row gets deleted from db but the datatable does not get refreshed. It still shows the old set of rows. How can I get the datatable to be refreshed?

Here is the code

```
   <h:form id="form">
     <p:dataTable  value="#{myController.displayList}" var="item" id="tbl">
       <p:column>
         <p:commandButton image="icon icon-delete"
                          id="del" action="#{myController.del}"
                          update="@form">    
           <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" 
              target="#{myController.selected}" for="del"/>
         </p:commandButton>
       </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>
   </h:form>
```

The displayList is

```
private List<Image> displayList = new ArrayList<Image>();

public List<Image> getDisplayList() {
        Student std = (Student) getSelected;
        displayList = this.ejbFacade.getImages(std.getId()); // this method gets the list of images which has status = 1
        return displayList;
}

public void setDisplayList(List<Image> displayList) {
    this.displayList = displayList;
}
```

//this is the del method which sets the flag for image to 0 (when del icon is pressed from view)
 public void del() {
        selected.setActiveStatus(0);
        MyController myController = (MyController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "myController");
        displayList.clear();
        myController.getFacade().edit(selected);
    }

Comment: Do you use cache on connection pool (like commons dbcp) ? Probably the problem is there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you are deleting the row from the DB but the `dataTable records list` isn't updated/refreshed. *Update you records* list by removing the deleted record from the list or by refill the list with the data from the DB(though this would be a bit resource consuming).
Show me java code!

PS:Also **congratulations** you asked the **thousandth** primefaces question! :) So I'm at your disposal...

Comment: I am trying to set the flag to 0 so that the images are not shown in the datatable. In the del method I set the flag to 0 and in datatable query I am getting the images with active = 1. Here is the del method 'public void del() {
        selected.setActiveStatus(false);
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        MyController myController = (MyController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "myController");        
        myController.getFacade().edit(selected);
    }'

Comment: @user1097366 Please post the code by editing your question, just like you put the xhtml code... Also I don't understand what is with this flag, post the `displayList` method

Answer (score 0):

if the displayList is the list that holds the values from the table

then

in the delete method you need to do

"set the id of the deleted row into the index variable"

and then do:

```
displayList.remove(index);
```

and then delete the row from db

Also try adding `process="@this"` to the commandButton